# MYSQL Has Many Join with condiitons

Tags: mysql, join

I'm try to write a simple JOIN that must meet two very elementary conditions. Consider these tables:

'attrbibute_variations'

```
id  | attribute_product_variation_id | variation_id
--------------------------------------------------
286 | 136                            | 57

287 | 136                            | 59

288 | 136                            | 73
```

'variations'

```
id | attribute_id
-----------------
57 | 1

59 | 5

73 | 12
```

I want to join on `variations` where these ids are matched:

```
attribute_product_variation_id = 136 
AND
variation_id = 57 AND 73
```

My SQL is as follows but gives an empty set:

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   `attribute_variations` AS `AttributeVariation` 
INNER JOIN
   variations` AS `Variation` 
      ON (
         (
            (
               `AttributeVariation`.`variation_id` = `Variation`.`id`
            ) 
            AND (
               `Variation`.`id` = 57
            )
         ) 
         AND (
            (
               `AttributeVariation`.`variation_id` = `Variation`.`id`
            ) 
            AND (
               `Variation`.`id` = 73
            )
         )
      ) 
WHERE
   `AttributeVariation`.`attribute_product_variation_id` = 136
```

Seems simple enough but the result is an empty set?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can\`t have `Variation`.`id` = 73 AND `Variation`.`id` = 57 at the same time nevermind you are repeating AttributeVariation`.`variation_id` = `Variation`.`id` for some reason.

Comment: Do i need a different type of JOIN then, this isn't complex

Comment: What are your expected results?  Generally this is handled with aggregation.

Comment: `ON AttributeVariation`.`variation_id` = `Variation`.`id` WHERE
   `AttributeVariation`.`attribute_product_variation_id` = 136` should be enough if I understand you.

Comment: @sgeddes I'm expecting a join to be made on ids 57 and 73 in this case

Comment: @Mihai that example doesn't take into the account the variation_ids 73 and 57 which should also be met

Comment: WHERE
   `AttributeVariation`.`attribute_product_variation_id` IN(53, 73)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you what you want, but does it with double use of the tables.  It is an alternative to using joins and having clause and aggregate counts.  The primary part of the query starts with the product variation that AT LEAST qualifies for the one id in question (57).  Then joins to the variations table to get the attribute value.  It ALSO joins to the same product variations table by the same attribute/product AND the variation ID = 73 (second id in question).  That second alias joins to variations by its ID to get the final attribute.

I would have indexes on your table by

```
table               index 
attrbibute_variations   ( variation_id, attribute_product_variation_id )
variations          ( id, attribute_id )

select
      av1.id,
      av1.attribute_product_variation_id,
      v1.attribute_id as Attribute1,
      v2.attribute_id as Attribute2
   from
      attrbibute_variations av1
         JOIN variations v1
            on av1.variation_id = v1.id
         join attrbibute_variations av2
           on av1.attribute_product_variation_id 
            = av2.attribute_product_variation_id
           AND av2.variation_id = 73
              join variations v2
                 on av2.variation_id = v2.id
   where
      av1.variation_id = 57
```

Then, if you wanted a third required attribute, you could copy/paste the section starting with AV2 and V2 aliases.

If the query cant even find a record with 57 variation_id, no need to look for the joins to the other(s) too.

Comment: Great thanks it works perfectly, I had to move a few things around to fit my live use case and plug it into my framework, very satisfying :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return `attribute_variations` that have both variation ids of 57 and 73 and return the joined results, this should work:

```
select *
from attribute_variations av
    join variations v on av.variation_id = v.id 
where av.attribute_product_variation_id = 136 and
      av.variation_id in (57,73) and 
      exists (
         select 1
         from attribute_variations av2
         where av.attribute_product_variation_id = av2.attribute_product_variation_id 
             and av2.variation_id in (57,73)
         group by av.attribute_product_variation_id 
         having count(distinct av.variation_id) = 2
     )
```

Comment: Thanks but that also returns an empty set

Comment: @AlanA -- perhaps you just need to add `where av.attribute_product_variation_id = 136`?

Comment: I have marked the other reply as the answer because I was able to work that into my framework's mysql helper, I don't have the knowledge to plug your answer in - thank you for your answer nonetheless!